# nested if statement is only returning the else statement unless first value is chosen | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested-loops

I am doing an assignment and everything is going well except my final if/else statement defaults to the else block unless I enter the first value I am trying to check and I think I understand why but I can't think of a way to prevent it. However, when I run the program without the else block the output is perfectly fine.

Input file:

```
LE1 Leicester
LE2 Oadby,Knighton,Highfields,Aylestone
LE3 Braunstone,Glenfield,Groby Road
LE4 BeaumontLeys,Belgrave,Birstall,Thurmaston
LE5 Hamilton,ThurnbyLodge,Evington
```

Code:

```
def area3(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    aList = list()
    bList = list()

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        f = line.split("\t")
        aList.append(f)

    for line in aList:
        for i in line[1:]:
            i = i.split(",")
            bList.append(i)

    for i in range(0, len(aList)):
        del aList[i][1]
        aList[i].append(bList[i])

    for j in aList:
        for x in j[1]:
            print(j[0], x)
    print("")

    x = input("Enter the name of the suburb to get its postcode: ")
    x = x.capitalize()

    for i in aList:
        for j in i[1]:
            if x == j:
                return "The postcode is: " + i[0]
            else:
                return "Not Found"

print(area3(input("Input filename: ")))
```

Output with the else block:

```
Input filename: postcode.txt
LE1 Leicester
LE2 Oadby
LE2 Knighton
LE2 Highfields
LE2 Aylestone
LE3 Braunstone
LE3 Glenfield
LE3 Groby Road
LE4 BeaumontLeys
LE4 Belgrave
LE4 Birstall
LE4 Thurmaston
LE5 Hamilton
LE5 ThurnbyLodge
LE5 Evington

Enter the name of the suburb to get its postcode: evington
Not Found
```

Output without the else block:

```
Input filename: postcode.txt
LE1 Leicester
LE2 Oadby
LE2 Knighton
LE2 Highfields
LE2 Aylestone
LE3 Braunstone
LE3 Glenfield
LE3 Groby Road
LE4 BeaumontLeys
LE4 Belgrave
LE4 Birstall
LE4 Thurmaston
LE5 Hamilton
LE5 ThurnbyLodge
LE5 Evington

Enter the name of the suburb to get its postcode: evington
The postcode is: LE5
```

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't return at the else statement. The return statement exits the function so it will stop iterating if it is not found at the first step. On a side not thanks for including an [mcve]

Comment: To clarify the comment from @EdekiOkoh you should still return "Not Found", but the return should be the last statement of the function instead of being within the loop.

Comment: Okay thanks I don't know how I managed to miss that. Works perfectly now!

Comment: @EdekiOkoh this is *not* a MRE.  An MRE would contain a hard-coded `aList`, not requiring that each of us edit an input file, not including 25 lines of code to process that file.

Comment: He included the 25 lines of code to process the file because the OP didn't know why the error was occurring. It very well could have been a processing issue where he deletes the input. But you are right, this is a complete example, and easily reproducible for me but maybe not you so not an MRE.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last part to so that "Not found" is only returned after the list has been fully iterated through.

```
for i in aList:
        for j in i[1]:
            if x == j:
                return "The postcode is: " + i[0]

return "Not Found"
```

Comment: It's slightly confusing to use the name `i` (or `j`) in a loop to represent the elements of the list, since those names are almost always used for indexes.